# How can I define a custom parent route for the default Sails.js REST API urls?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In Sails.js, when I create an API endpoint with `sails generate api <name> [param1, param2, ...]`, it defaults to serving a REST api based on the name of the file - i.e. `generate api users` would create an endpoint at `localhost/users` that would respond to GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. requests.

I'd like to keep this functionality, but nest it under, for example, `/api/v1/` to keep my routes clean.  Ideally there would be a way to configure Blueprint to serve the api from a different path.  I know I could modify `config/routes.js`, but there's no way to map all the functionality without defining lots of custom routes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [in the Blueprint configuration docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints)

In `config/blueprints.js` add:

```
prefix: '/api',
restPrefix: '/v1',
```